# Pass positional argument to funtion

Tags: bash

I encounter error when try to pass argument to function.

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/bash
    program=$(basename $0)
    file_info () {
        # file_info: function to display file infomation.
        echo "this is $1" 
        if [[ -e $1 ]]; then
            echo "Paramater 1 eq $1"
            echo -e "\nFile Type:"
            file "$1"
            echo -e "\n File Status:"
            stat "$1"
        else
            echo "$program: usage: $program file" >&2
            return 1
        fi 
    }
    file_info
```

I test it

```
    $ bash file_info.sh answer.sh
    this is .
    file_info.sh: usage: file_info.sh file
```

Nevertheless the file exist.

```
    $ [[ -e answer.sh ]] && echo "answer.sh exists"
    answer.sh exists
```

How to pass positional argument into function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass script arguments into a function, change the last line to:

```
file_info "$@"
```

Comment: Is it a compulsory that $@ should be quoted? unquoted works properly.

Comment: @tool: It is compulsory. Unquoted does not work properly on all arguments; it just happened to work on the ones you tried. It won't work if an argument includes whitespace, or a glob character (like `*`), etc. There's no extra charge for quotes.

Comment: @Tool, I suggest you to see errors or learn good practices, use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)